# Modify the color of a FlatIcon icon in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, icons

I have a FlatIcon icon and i modified it via css like this:

```
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {

    font-size: 55px;
    color: red;

}
```

The problem is that i have to modify the color via jquery as well.

I tried several ways, like this:

```
$('.flaticon-car:before').css('color',"#4286f4");
$('.flaticon-car:after').css('color',"#4286f4");
$('.flaticon-car').css('color',"#4286f4");
$('.flaticon-car:before').css({"color":"#4286f4"});
$('.flaticon-car:after').css({"color":"#4286f4"});
$('.flaticon-car').css({"color":"#4286f4"});
```

After that, i tried this:

```
$('.flaticon-car').click(function () {
    $(this).css('color','#4286f4');
});
```

Nothing worked for me.Do you have any ideea how can i do this?

Comment: You can not style `:after/before` from Jquery

Comment: Ok, but how can i change the color?

Comment: Use custom CSS class that modifying color of icon and using jquery add that class to element

Comment: so, i have this: `<i class="flaticon-car car-class"></i>`
and in js i have this: $('.car-class').css('color','#4286f4');

In inspector i can see that the color is added to the <i></i> element, but nothing it's happening...

Comment: here is the answer you want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin/49618941#49618941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not style `:after/before` from Jquery

The trick is to `toggle` class

See example:

```js
$('.className').click(function () {
   $( this ).toggleClass("newClassName");
});
```

```css
.className:after,.newClassName:after
{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    font-size: 55px;
    background: red;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    left: 120px;
}

.newClassName:after
{
    background: #4286f4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="className"> hello className</div>
```

Comment: It did the trick! Thank you very much

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: there is a way to style pseudo element with jquery : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin/49618941#49618941

Comment: @TemaniAfif nice one (as allways :) ) but `css-variables` not support all browser(I know that pseudo also not...)

Comment: only IE will fail (as usual) but who care about IE ;)

Comment: Loll You right... I hate IE(but in my work i must make IE works)